# How do I make a command run, but then in the command, make it wait for a users input?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def nuke(ctx):
    await ctx.send('''Are you sure you want to nuke this channel? This will completely erase all messages from it!
type proceed to continue, and return to return. ''')
```

I want to make it be able to take a users input from this command and stay locked in this command until they enter a valid choice. (like dank Memer's search command). Could ya'll help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`discord.Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) to get user input, here's an example:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def nuke(ctx):
    await ctx.send('''Are you sure you want to nuke this channel? This will completely erase all messages from it!
type proceed to continue, and return to return. ''')
    answer = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author and message != "") # Gets user input and checks if message is not empty and was sent by the same user
    answer = answer.content # Gets content of message

    while answer.lower() != "continue" and answer.lower() != "return": # Loop until user enters a correct answer
        await ctx.send("Only enter 'continue' or 'return'!")
        await ctx.send('''Are you sure you want to nuke this channel? This will completely erase all messages from it!
type proceed to continue, and return to return. ''')
        answer = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author and message != "") # Gets user input and checks if message is not empty and was sent by the same user
        answer = answer.content # Gets content of message
    
    if answer.lower() == "continue":
        # Do something if user chooses 'continue'
    elif answer.lower() == "return":
        # Do something if user chooses 'return'
```

You can also do this without a while loop, instead you can adjust your check to see if the message contains "continue" or "return", for example:

```
@client.command()
async def nuke(ctx):
    await ctx.send('''Are you sure you want to nuke this channel? This will completely erase all messages from it!
type proceed to continue, and return to return. ''')

    answer = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author and message != "" and (message.content.lower() == "continue" or message.content.lower() == "return"))
    answer = answer.content
    
    if answer.lower() == "continue":
        # Do something if user chooses 'continue'
    elif answer.lower() == "return":
        # Do something if user chooses 'return'
```

Comment: The command worked, thank you!! Just one more question tho- if the user enters an invalid command, how would the system check and display an error?

Comment: Nevermind, i got that down, thanks. And like, if the user doesn't type it correctly after 2 times, how would I make the command end?

Comment: You can add the user and their attempts to a dictionary and if the attempts is equal to 2 then end the command.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

This should help you... it waits until you write 'proceed' or the time of 60 seconds run out.

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def nuke(ctx):

    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel and message.content.lower() == "proceed"

    try:

        await ctx.send(
            f'Are you sure you want to nuke this channel? \n This will completely erase messages from it! \n'
            'type __proceed__ to continue, and return to return.')
        await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
        # You can now fill this with your action

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        #this will react if you no react in time
        await ctx.send('You took to long')
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=3)
```